# Creating my first docker image with a local zip

Tags: docker, dockerfile

very new to Docker here. I am trying to use a maven 2.1.0 zip to create a docker image.
my

dockerfile.docker file is :

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM scratch
LABEL maintainer="Myname"
LABEL maintainer="myemail"
RUN wget HTTP://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/apache-maven-2.1.0-bin.zip
RUN unzip
```

I am not exactly sure if I am doing this right

```
docker build -t apache-maven:2.1.0 .
```

Essentially I just wanted to create this image locally so I could then push it out to my targeted endpoint. Any help realizing what I did wrong would be appreciated. Whenever I run this build command it tells me it failed to read the dockerfile and that there's no such file or directory.

Comment: The file must be named exactly `Dockerfile`, with that capitalization and no extension.  You probably don't want to start `FROM scratch`, which will not include `wget` or anything else at all; a more likely starting point is the [Docker Hub `maven` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven).

Comment: Okay, I was under the assumption I couldn't pull anything but the latest revision of maven from that repository. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

By default, it will try to find the file with the exact name `Dockerfile`.

If for any reason, you want to have a different file name like your scenario, you should use next:

```
docker build -f dockerfile.docker -t apache-maven:2.1.0 .
```

Detail refers to [Specify a Dockerfile (-f)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specify-a-dockerfile--f)